# Spring Security blocks POST requests despite SecurityConfig

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a REST API based on Spring Boot (`spring-boot-starter-web`) where I use Spring Security (`spring-security-core` e `spring-security-config`) to protect the different endpoints.

The authentication is done by using a local database that contains  users with two different sets of roles: `ADMIN` and`USER`. `USER` should be able to`GET` all API endpoints and `POST` to endpoints based on`routeA`. `ADMIN` should be able to do the same as`USER` plus `POST` and`DELETE` to endpoints based on `routeB

However the behavior I'm getting is that I can do `GET` requests to any endpoint but `POST` requests always return `HTTP 403 Forbidden` for either type of user - `ADMIN` and `USER` - which is not expected what I'm expecting based on my `SecurityConfiguration`.

Any ideas of what am I missing?

---

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Using database as the authentication provider.");
        builder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().
            authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/routeA/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/routeB/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/routeB/*").hasRole("ADMIN").and().
            requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache()).and().
            httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and().
            cors();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

**RouteBController .java**

```
@RestController
public class RouteBController {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RouteBController.class);

    public RouteBController() { }

    @RequestMapping(value = "routeB", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStuff() {
        return "Got a hello world!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "routeB", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postStuff() {
        return "Posted a hello world!";
    }

}
```

**RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint.java**

```
@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("AppNameHere");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

***BEFORE** disabling the CSFR as a way of fixing this issue, please check the resources on [Mohd Waseem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62606596/9596058) to better understand why it is important and to have an idea of how it can be properly set up. As [RCaetano has said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026694/spring-security-blocks-post-requests-despite-securityconfig/51039444?noredirect=1#comment119517127_51039444), **CSFR is here to help us from attacks and it should not be disabled blindly**.*

*Since this answer still explained the 2 issues on my original questions, I'll leave it as the marked answer to create awareness about possible issues with the CSFT and security routes but **don't take it literally**.*

---

There were 2 issues in `SecurityConfiguration.java` that made it misbehave.

Although the `403 Forbidden` error message didn't contain any message indication of why it was failing (see example below) it turns out it was due to having [CSRF](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/) enabled. Disabling it allowed for `POST` and `DELETE` requests to be processed.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-06-26T09:17:19.672+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/routeB"
}
```

Also the expression used in `antMatched(HttpMethod, String)` for `RouteB` was incorrect because `/routeB/*` expects it to have *something* after `/`. The correct configurtion is `/routeB/**` since more paths *can* be present (*or not*).

---

The **corrected** `SecurityConfiguration.java` is

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().
        authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/routeA/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/routeB/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/routeB/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().
        requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache()).and().
        httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and().
        cors().and().
        csrf().disable();
}
```

---

> **Source:** [StackOverflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309618/spring-security-bloqueia-pedidos-post-apesar-das-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

Comment: CSRF... phew! THANKS!

Comment: I know this question is a few months / years old, but from what I know CSRF shouldn't be disabled in production, should it?

Comment: This solution should not be used blindly because there is a reason why CSRF is enabled by default: to protect against certain types of attacks

Comment: @Igor as it was said in these comments, CSRF should not be disabled blindly. You can tune it to your needs to avoid the issue I was having while maintaining the security benefits it offers

Comment: @RCaetano thanks for your comment, I didn't see that this had been commented on before. I'll leave the answer as I believe it creates awareness about possible issues with the CSFT and security routes but I pointed out the better solutions/resources shared in this post.

Comment: Massive help finding this question! Just to add to this, if you want to selectively disable CSRF (say on a publicly exposed API) you can add an ANT matcher to csrf. e.g. `.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/some/rest/api")`

Answer (score 5):

It's simple CSRF enabled issue that doesn't allow POST requests. I faced the same problem here's the solution: (**Explained**)

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/form").hasRole("ADMIN")  // Specific api method request based on role.
            .antMatchers("/home","/basic").permitAll()  // permited urls to guest users(without login).
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()       // not specified form page to use default login page of spring security
            .permitAll()
             .and()
        .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")  // delete memory of browser after logout
         
        .and()
        .rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret"); // remember me check box enabled.
    
    http.csrf().disable();  // ADD THIS CODE TO DISABLE CSRF IN PROJECT.**
}
```

**Above code:**

> ```java
> http.csrf().disable();
> ```

**will solve the problem.**

Answer (score 5):

> **Cross-site request forgery** is a web security vulnerability that allows an attacker to induce users to perform actions that they do not
> intend to perform.

In your case disabling **CSRF** protection exposes user to this vulnerability.

> Note: If it was pure Rest API with O-Auth protection then CSRF was not
> needed. [Should I use CSRF protection on Rest API endpoints?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints)

But In your case when user logs in a session is created and cookie is returned in response and without **CSRF** token Attacker can exploit it and perform **CSRF**.

It wouldn't be a good idea to disable CSRF instead you can configure your app to return CSRF token in response headers and then use it in all your subsequent state changing calls.

Add this line of code in your **SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
// CSRF tokens handling
http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

**CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter.java**

```
public class CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    protected static final String REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "_csrf";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME = "X-CSRF-HEADER";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_PARAM_NAME = "X-CSRF-PARAM";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_TOKEN_NAME = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, javax.servlet.FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

        if (token != null) {
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME, token.getHeaderName());
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_PARAM_NAME, token.getParameterName());
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_TOKEN_NAME, token.getToken());
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Header Response form Server:
[image]

Note that we now have CSRF token in the header. This will not change untill the session expires.
Also read: [Spring Security’s CSRF protection for REST services: the client side and the server side](https://www.codesandnotes.be/2015/02/05/spring-securitys-csrf-protection-for-rest-services-the-client-side-and-the-server-side/#:%7E:text=In%20Spring%20Security%2C%20the%20CSRF,be%20returned%20by%20the%20server.&text=The%20first%20GET%20request%20fails%20because%20we%27re%20not%20authenticated.) for better understanding.

Comment: (Others) Be sure to use the right import: `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken` or you can get:
`class org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfToken`