# How to get access to JHipster entities from the React client?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jhipster

I would like to list every record for a specific entity called google-results on a page accessible via localhost:8080/public/

I have duplicated the tsx file in /entities/google-results/google-result.tsx into /modules/public/home.tsx, I have created a new route and bound it that component.

It compiles successfully but when I hit localhost/public, the javascript console shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>   (Unauthorized)

[image]

What could be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: How did you configure security on server for this new API endpoint? Looks like you did not disable authorization for it, check SecurityConfiguration.java

Comment: It worked, thanks. I used this question as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026694/spring-security-blocks-post-requests-despite-securityconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in SecurityConfiguration.java:

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN", "USER")
.antMatchers("/public/**").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN", "USER")
```

It is obviously not recommended to let it like that but that gives an idea of how it works.

Comment: You should probably come with a stricter solution with little more work, alternatively you can combine this with `@Secured` annotations on your REST controllers to restrict permissions in a more fine-grained way.