# How to configure CSRF Token in SpringBoot 2.7

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

We are building a simple app with SpringBoot 2.7 and are running into issues with the CSRF token setup. User operations (POST requests) return 403 forbidden. This is contained in an AWS ecs cluster and is running SpringBoot 2.7 with SpringBootSecurity 5.8 The csrf token is blocking post operations and I am not sure what the correct setup would look like. We can only perform actions with CSRF disabled.

**EDIT: After further troubleshooting we can see there is no xsrf token response header coming in the post request of the file upload.**

Here's the current setup.

**The SpringBoot dependancies:**

```
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.12")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.7.12")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1")
    implementation("com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.54")
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:secretsmanager:2.20.79")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.8.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.8.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.8.0")
    implementation("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1")
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
    implementation("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.1")
```

**The JWT filter:**

```
package com.place.sftp.portal.security;

import com.place.sftp.portal.constant.Path;
import com.place.sftp.portal.model.SecretHolder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    private static final String BEARER = "Bearer ";
    private static final String OPTIONS = "OPTIONS";

    @Autowired
    private SecretHolder secretHolder;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {

        if(
                Path.AUTHENTICATE_FULL.equals(request.getRequestURI()) ||
                        Path.IS_CONNECTED_FULL.equals(request.getRequestURI()) ||
                        OPTIONS.equals(request.getMethod()))
        {
            logger.info("start: doFilterInternal");
            CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
            response.setHeader(csrfToken.getHeaderName(), csrfToken.getToken());
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            logger.info("start: processJWT");
            processJWT(request, response, filterChain);
        }
    }

    private void processJWT(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException
    {
        logger.info("Processing JWT");
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        if(validAuthHeader(authorizationHeader))
        {
            String token = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            try
            {
                validateJWT(token, filterChain, request, response);
                logger.info("JWT validated successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.error("error in if ",e);
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.info("Error in else");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    private boolean validAuthHeader(String authorizationHeader)
    {
        return authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith(BEARER);
    }

    private void validateJWT(String token, FilterChain filterChain,
                             HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        logger.info("starting: JWT Validation");
        logger.info("token is");
        logger.info(token);
        logger.info("secret is");
        //logger.info(secretHolder.getSecret());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = SECRET_VALUE_HERE
        logger.info("got auth");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        logger.info("set security context successfully");
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        logger.info("ending: JWT Validation");
        response.setHeader(csrfToken.getHeaderName(), csrfToken.getToken());
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**Security Config:**

```
package com.place.sftp.portal.security;

import com.place.sftp.portal.constant.Path;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCache;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.SimpleSavedRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
{
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        logger.info("Configure CSRF Token.");

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.requestMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/static/**",
                                "/*.ico", "/*.json", "/*.png", "/api/isconnected", "/api/listchildnodes","/api/authenticate","/api/upload").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/74521360/65681
                        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler())
                )
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        logger.info("Authorize CSRF Token.");

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestCache refererRequestCache() {
        return new HttpSessionRequestCache() {
            @Override
            public void saveRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
                String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
                if (referrer == null) {
                    referrer = request.getRequestURL().toString();
                }
                request.getSession().setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST",
                        new SimpleSavedRequest(referrer));

            }
        };
    }

}
```

**Frontend Post:**

```
    const UploadModal = ({ open, handleClose }: UploadModalProps) => {
    const [fileData, setFileData] = useState<File | null>(null);
    const folderPath = "";
    const [cookies] = useCookies(["XSRF-TOKEN"]);

    const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.target.files) {
            setFileData(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    };

    const handleFileUpload = async () => {
        if (fileData) {
            const formData: FormData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", fileData);
            formData.append("folderPath", folderPath);
            try {
                const response = await axios.post(
                    `${process.env.API_URL}/api/upload`,
                    formData,
                    {
                        withCredentials: true,
                        headers: { "X-XSRF-TOKEN": cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"] }
                    }
                );
                if (response) {
                    toast.success(
                        "File Upload Successfully",
                        successToastOptions
                    );

                    setFileData(null);
                } else {
                    toast.error("File Upload Failed", errorToastOptions);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                toast.error("File Upload Failed", errorToastOptions);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried applying this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62606596/9596058)? It suggests adding this line to your Security Config's filter chain:

```
http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

With CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter.java defined as:

```
public class CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    protected static final String REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "_csrf";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME = "X-CSRF-HEADER";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_PARAM_NAME = "X-CSRF-PARAM";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_TOKEN_NAME = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, javax.servlet.FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

        if (token != null) {
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME, token.getHeaderName());
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_PARAM_NAME, token.getParameterName());
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_TOKEN_NAME, token.getToken());
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```